# Pseudo-elements move up 1px only in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Not sure what to make of this. Here's the page: http://veloci-rabbit.tumblr.com/

At the bottom, there's two labels that say "Post Type" and "Tag". When you click them, they'll open up (that functionality hasn't been added yet, but the appearance of the label works as intended). You can click both labels to open up both.

In the latest versions of Firefox and IE, this is working perfectly. In Chrome, it only works if one label is open. If you open up both, the two pseudo elements of the .labelname divs move down 1px. Not sure why this happens.

For reference, here's the relevant CSS and HTML of the labels:

```
.footer.labelcontainer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
}
.footer.label {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 7.5px;
    padding: 0 9px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.footer.label.opened::before {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%; height: 18px;
    margin-top: -18px; margin-left: -11px;
    padding: 0 0 0 22px;
}
.footer.label.opened::after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: -23px;
    margin-left: -18px;
    padding-right: 36px;
}
.footer.label.opened {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
.footer.labelname {
    margin-top: 2px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -user-select: none;
}
.opened .footer.labelname::before, .opened .footer.labelname::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 7px; height: 7px;
    background: transparent;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    top: -7px;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
.opened .footer.labelname::before {
    border-right: 2px solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    transform: translate(-200%,0);
}
.opened .footer.labelname::after {
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    transform: translate(100%,0);
}

        <div class="footer labelcontainer">
            <div class="footer label unopened"><p class="footer labelname">POST TYPE</p></div>
            <div class="footer label unopened"><p class="footer labelname">TAGS</p></div>
        </div>
```